# nginx and woocommerce side cart error: 'mozHidden' and 'mozVisibilityState' are deprecated

Tags: wordpress, nginx, woocommerce

With woocommerce, on localhost it's fine and work with nice.
But after I put online my side-cart not work
here is the link 
http://cherishinstyle.com/shop/clutch-bags/butterfly-flinders-hand-clutch/

when we click cart there is side cart will appear but it's got white page, I'm using nginx for server thanks.

when I try use firefox debug im just got this message:

> 'mozHidden' and 'mozVisibilityState' are deprecated.  Please use the unprefixed 'hidden' and 'visibilityState' instead.

Comment: Looks like this debug message is unrelated, and pretty much explains the problem: two firefox config variables are defined which are now deprecated for use.